# How do I generate all the dates of Sunday between 2 dates in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I generate all the dates of *Sunday* between 2 dates in oracle SQL?

Example if I want all the Sundays between *"01/10/2018"* and *"31/12/2018"* the output

```
will be:
07/10/2018
14/10/2018
21/10/2018
...
30/12/2018
```

Also how do I generate all the dates between 2 dates?

Example: from *"01/12/2018"* to *"31/12/2018"*

Output will be:

```
01/12/2018
02/12/2018
03/12/2018
...
31/12/2018
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit the question to show what you've tried. Like this we will be able to better understand your problem/question and thus we will be able to better help you. It is best to provide a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Answer (score 5):

Here's how; the CTE (`dates`) creates a "calendar" of all dates starting from `2018-10-01`, for number of days between `2018-10-01` and `2018-12-31`. This answers your 2nd question.

For the 1st question, using `TO_CHAR` function with appropriate format mask (`dy`) and date language (because, if I didn't use it, you'd get Croatian names as that's my default language), select all Sundays.

```
SQL> with dates as
  2    (select date '2018-10-01' + level - 1 datum
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= date '2018-12-31' - date '2018-10-01' + 1
  5    )
  6  select datum
  7  From dates
  8  where to_char(datum, 'dy', 'nls_date_language = english') = 'sun';

DATUM
-----------
07-oct-2018
14-oct-2018
21-oct-2018
28-oct-2018
04-nov-2018
11-nov-2018
18-nov-2018
25-nov-2018
02-dec-2018
09-dec-2018
16-dec-2018
23-dec-2018
30-dec-2018

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query does it.

First generate rows using connect by clause, each of the row will have the value of "level" column incremented by 1
Also get the day_of_week per date
Filter out the records where day_of_week='sun'

```
with data
  as (
    select to_date('1/10/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')+level as sun_day
           ,to_char(to_date('1/10/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')+level,'dy') day_of_week
      from dual
    connect by level<=to_date('31/12/2018','dd/mm/yyyy') - to_date('1/10/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')  
      )
select sun_day
  from data
where day_of_week='sun'
```

For the second part of the query simply remove the filter on the day_of_week

```
with data
  as (
    select to_date('1/10/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')+level as sun_day
           ,to_char(to_date('1/10/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')+level,'dy') day_of_week
      from dual
    connect by level<=to_date('31/12/2018','dd/mm/yyyy') - to_date('1/10/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')  
      )
select sun_day
  from data;
```

Comment: if i change day_of_week = 'mon', why doesn't it show 01/10/2018

Comment: If the edges are to be considered (ie do you want to include 1/10/2018 and 31/12/2018) as valid values in the output then need to change the query as "to_char(to_date('1/10/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')+level-1,'dy')"

Comment: Depending on the region settings of the database, tochar(dy) might not return 'sun'. The region should be forced in the to char to make this answer more internationally robust

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    to_char(date,'DD-MON-YYYY')
from
    dates
where
    (trunc(date) >= '01/12/2018'
    and
        trunc(date)<= '31/12/2018')
    and
        to_char(date,'DAY') ='SUNDAY';
```

Comment: Why not trunc for the day number too? Also worth nothing that not all countries have Sunday as the 7th day so this should really use a forced nls setting

Comment: trunc I had just used in case the format is date/time type then I saw the query it involved only date and time was already excluded so by that i just wrote it simply.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Comment: @Robert Columbia I think when the code has enough to say it should be the way it is and this hasnt been copied so that i could provide any reference. If you will see all my other answers there hasnt been a single one where I have not mentioned what it is for. Just for this I felt like code has enough to say.